# Why Popen.communicate returns the satus of another subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, reactjs, django, subprocess

I have codes that starts Django server and React server at the same time.
Here are the codes:
**back_server.py**

```
import os
import subprocess

def run_server():
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    target_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, 'marketBack/BackServer')

    subprocess.Popen(['python', f'{target_dir}/manage.py', 'runserver'], universal_newlines=True)
```

**front_server.py**

```
import os
import subprocess

def run_server():
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    target_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, 'marketPlaying/market-playing')
    os.chdir(target_dir)

    process = subprocess.Popen(['npm', 'start'], universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
    return process
```

**server.py**

```
import back_server
import front_server

def run_server_all():
    back_server.run_server()
    front_server.run_server().communicate()

run_server_all()
```

When I check the status of the front_server using `subprocess.communicate()`, it also returns the output of the back_server. Doesn't subprocess.Popen create independent process? Why does `front_server.run_server().communicate()` returns the status of back_server too?

Comment: "When I check the status of the front_server using subprocess.communicate(), it also returns the output of the back_server." - what makes you think that? You're not actually examining the `communicate` output.

Comment: @user2357112 Because it shows me that Django server and React server are running...?

Comment: That has nothing to do with `communicate` or what `communicate` returns. The subprocesses are writing output to their inherited stdout and stderr streams, because you didn't specify any other stdout/stderr handling. Any output you see is coming from that, not from `communicate`.